# SQL Query Average

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I am trying to work out a sql query to work out the average off 3 values to 2 decimal places.

```
SELECT RatingId, Productivity, CodeQuality, AgileProcess
     , ROUND(AVG(Productivity + CodeQuality + AgileProcess) / 3, 2) AS Average
FROM DeveloperRating
GROUP BY RatingId, Productivity, CodeQuality, AgileProcess`
```

Productivity, CodeQuality, AgileProcess are all values currently set in DB.

If the values are set as follows:
Productivity = 2 CodeQuality = 8 AgileProcess = 4

I get the answer 4. I would like the answer to be 4.66 ?

Can anyone help?

Comment: MySQL does not do integer division, so it is unlikely that you would get an integer.  This SQL Fiddle, for instance, returns the correct result:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use aggregate functions here! You're grouping for each row in your table. Other than that, you may need to cast your values to `DOUBLE` to get what you need.

Try:

```
 select ratingId, productivity, codeQuality, agileProcess
      , round(cast(productivity as double) + 
              cast(codeQuality as double) + 
              cast(agileProcess as double) / 3,2)
 from developerRating
```

Comment: @RichardQuinn if you find this answer useful, up-vote it, or accept it